# Erro ao Customizar Rotas MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, route

O erro ocorre no método (RegisterRoutes) em RouteConfig.cs na linha

`routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`

Ao executar no navegador:

*** The built-in constraint resolver of type 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' could not resolve the following built-in constraint: 'string'. ***

> [HttpException (0x80004005): The built-in constraint resolver of type
>   'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' could not resolve the following
>   built-in constraint: 'string'.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10042604
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro significa que em algum lugar, em uma Rota, você especificou algo como

```
[Route("AlgumaRota/{algumparametro:string}")]
```

A restrição *inline* `string` não é necessária pois ela já é o tipo assumido proveniente da URL. Inclusive tal restrição *inline* nem é disponível pelo `DefaultInlineConstraintResolver`, como o erro lhe indica.

A seção *Route Constraints* [desse artigo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) fornece uma tabela que lista todas as restrições suportadas.

Para resolver o seu problema, apenas remova a restrição `string`

```
[Route("AlgumaRota/{algumparametro}")]
```

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente isso